# How was a newbie able to ask eight questions in six hours on a single site?

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, rate-limiting

A new user managed to ask eight questions on History SE in the past six hours.

I thought that there was a six question limit a day. That is per twenty four hour period.

Or was it an instance where someone managed to ask two questions just before "midnight" (GMT), July 26, and the remaining six questions the morning of the following day, July 27, because that is how "day" is defined?

Comment: Per [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), the six-question-per-day limit is only implemented on Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Mathematics, and not on the other sites.

Comment: although as pointed above it currently works on 4 sites, I think it is technically possible to establish such limit at any site. Math.SE shows an example on how to do that, they started meta discussion, it has got solid support of site community and after that company staff enabled this restriction for them. You can see how it worked at their meta: [Should we ask for Question Quotas like those that have been available for the big three?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi)

Answer (score 10):

There does indeed exist a six question limit per day.

It is buried in the ridiculous amount of rules surrounding all kind of rate limiting in the [FAQ on that topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). I can imagine you missed that subtlety:

> On Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Mathematics (not active on all other sites)
>
> - maximum of 6 questions per day

Only four sites in the network have that rate limit enabled. History.SE is not in that list. You need the other quality mechanisms to stop these unwanted contributions: downvote, flag, close and delete. That should put such accounts in a quality ban. In the end that is more effective but a bit of a pain to achieve when there is a sudden flood with not enough voters around.